# E(X)/E(Y) compared to E(X/Y)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, random-variables, expectation

Is there any sort of inequality stating the relationship between the two?

1) if X and Y are independent they are equal, I think. Since 1/Y will be independent to X too as well right?

2) but what if two are dependent?

Comment: If $X, Y$ are independent then $E[X/Y] = E[X]E[1/Y]$.  But $E[1/Y]$ is not the same as $1/E[Y]$.

Comment: On the other hand, if $Y=aX$ then $E[X]/E[Y] = E[X/Y]$, assuming no divide by zero issues.

Answer (score 6):

If $X, Y$ are independent then 
$$ E\left[\frac{X}{Y}\right] = E[X]E\left[\frac{1}{Y}\right]$$
In general $E[\frac{1}{Y}]$ is not the same as $\frac{1}{E[Y]}$. Let's assume $E[X]$, $E[\frac{1}{Y}]$ are finite.

The function $1/y$ is strictly convex over the domain $y>0$.  So if 
$Y>0$ with prob 1, then by Jensen’s inequality we have: 
$$ E\left[\frac{1}{Y}\right] \geq \frac{1}{E[Y]} $$
with equality if and only if $Var(Y)=0$. So if $X,Y$ independent and if $Y>0$ with prob 1 then

- $E[X]=0 \implies E\left[\frac{X}{Y}\right] = 0= \frac{E[X]}{E[Y]}$.
- $E[X]>0 \implies E\left[\frac{X}{Y}\right] \geq \frac{E[X]}{E[Y]}$ with equality if and only if $Var(Y)=0$.
- $E[X]<0 \implies E\left[\frac{X}{Y}\right] \leq \frac{E[X]}{E[Y]}$ with equality if and only if $Var(Y)=0$.

Comment: btw why is 1/Y and X independent if X and Y are independent? linearity of exp doesnt apply here

Comment: @jamesblack : Linearity of expectation means $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]$ and that holds regardless of whether or not $X$ and $Y$ are independent.  If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, intuitively it means that information about $Y$ tells you nothing about $X$, so information about some function of $Y$ (such as $e^Y$, $Y^2$, or $1/Y$) also tells you nothing about $X$.  More formally (and avoiding divide-by-zero issues) we get $P[X\leq x, 1/Y\leq z] = P[X\leq x, Y\geq 1/z] = P[X\leq x]P[Y\geq 1/z] = P[X\leq x]P[1/Y\leq z]$ where the second equality holds because $X, Y$ are independent.

Comment: thank you and why is $E[X]>0 \implies E\left[\frac{X}{Y}\right] \geq \frac{E[X]}{E[Y]}$ with equality if and only if $Var(Y)=0$? what makes it greated? like what does E(X/Y) specifically equal to if possible

Comment: also do you mean  if X,Y independent and if Y>0 with prob 1 or dependent? since if independent, then we have the equality there is no point in estbliashing inequality

Comment: If $a>0$ and $r\leq s$ then $ar \leq as$. My answer above indeed only considers the case when $X, Y$ are independent. As I described in my answer, it is _not true_ that if $X, Y$ are independent then $E[X/Y]=E[X]/E[Y]$.  On the other hand, note that I have already given an exact equality for $E[X/Y]$, that is, I have already given what it is specifically equal to.

Comment: You can get intuition by considering the following example: Let $X, Y$ be independent with $P[Y=1]=P[Y=3]=1/2$, $P[X=1]=P[X=3]=1/2$.  Please compute $E[Y]$ and $E[1/Y]$ and compare them. Also, please compute $E[X/Y]$ and $E[X]/E[Y]$ and compare them.

Comment: so what bout if they are dependent? that is part of my confusion as well thanks.

Comment: I think you need to focus on the case when they are independent, to understand that case thoroughly.  Can you compute the expectations for the example I gave? What did you find?

Comment: @jamesblack : I observe that you responded immediately to multiple rounds of feedback, except for the one time when I asked you to do some work.  Is it correct to assume that you had trouble computing $E[Y]$ and $E[1/Y]$ for a random variable $Y$ such that $P[Y=1]=P[Y=3]=1/2$?