# Prove or disprove $ E\left[\frac{.75X-bY}{X+Y}\right] = \frac{.75E[X]-bE[Y]}{E[X]+E[Y]} $

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, statistics, proof-writing

If the specific case below is really true , you're welcome to generalize it .

When $ X\sim Geo(.5) , Y\sim Geo(\sqrt{b}) , b\in [0,1]$ and they're independent , I suspect that (other approaches solving the same problem give same final answer)
$$
E\left[\frac{.75X-bY}{X+Y}\right] = \frac{.75E[X]-bE[Y]}{E[X]+E[Y]}
$$

is it true ?

---

(edit) **Brute force :**
I obtained the equivalent equation that I need to prove/disprove
$$
\sum_{x=1,2,...} \sum_{y=1,2,...} \frac{.75x - by }{x+y} (.5)^x(1-\sqrt{b})^{y} 
= \frac{1.5 + b - 2.5\sqrt{b}}{2\sqrt{b} +1}
$$
but I'm unable to deal with $\frac{.75x - by }{x+y}$ .
LHS and RHS very close so I have difficulty finding a nice function to replace $\frac{.75x - by }{x+y}$ to force an inequality . e.g. replace with $1,-1$ didn't work

---

(you may omit since I'm focusing on brute forcing now) **Other Attempts :**

I'm not very rigorous below .

$.75X-bY , X+Y$ seem to be dependent , because given $.75X-bY = u$ , we can deduce that $X = (4/3)u + (4/3)bY$ , so $X+Y = (4/3)u + (4/3)bY + Y  > (4/3)u$ since $Y\ge 1$ , when $u\ge 3/2$ , this information becomes useful . If this's true , then expectation won't even factor . I'm unable to proceed .

Suppose $.75X-bY , X+Y$ are independent , if I could show
$E\left[\frac{1}{X+Y}\right] = \frac{1}{E[X+Y]}$
by [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2707433) then I'm done . However , $Var(X+Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) = 2 - \frac{1-\sqrt{b}}{b}  \neq 0$ so I'm still unable to proceed .

Numerical trials suggest there's a difference :
$$
\begin{array}{c|lc}
b & \text{RHS} & \text{mean of abs(LHS-RHS)}^*  \\
\hline
.05 & 0.1972 & 0.0479 \\
.25 & 0.2500 &  0.0010 \\
.5 & 0.2322 &  0.0347 \\
.75 & 0.2010 & 0.0654 \\
.95 & 0.1736 & 0.0873 
\end{array}
$$
$*$ Using $20$ samples of LHS $E\left[\frac{.75X-bY}{X+Y}\right] $ computed from $20000$ samples of $\frac{.75X-bY}{X+Y}$ .

Comment: Have you tried calculating both the LHS and the RHS and see what expressions they evaluate to?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye Thanks for suggesting , I'll try a bit later . Seems like this's the only way ? I wonder if there're some theorems that may help to avoid doing this since I'm not well versed in this area  ...

Comment: @HelloGoodbye  It turns out I'm unable to do it , especially due to the fraction of sums (on the RHS) , I don't know any theorem to deal with it ...

Comment: @HelloGoodbye maybe for now I should inspect the cause of my suspicion ...

Comment: The right hand side should be the easiest to calculate. Both $X$ and $Y$ are distributed according to geometric distributions, and a geometrically distributed variable parameterized by $p$ has the [expectation value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution#Moments_and_cumulants) $\frac{1}{p}$, so you have $E[X]=\frac{1}{0.5}$ and $E[Y]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}$. For the left hand side, however, you need to use the formula $E(f(X, Y)) = \displaystyle \sum_{X,Y}P(X,Y)f(X,Y)$, where $P(X,Y)$ is the joint probability for $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye Thank you . I edited the post with my latest difficulty .

Comment: Maybe try a variable substitution in the LHS and see if that helps? Instead of calculating the sum $\displaystyle \sum_{x=1,2,\dots} \sum_{y=1,2,\dots} \dots$, calculate $\displaystyle \sum_{p=2,3,\dots}\ \sum_{q=-p+2,-p,-p+2,\dots,p-2} \dots$, where $p=x+y$ and $q=x-y$. You should get a sum with $p$ in the denominator, though, so I'm not sure you will be able to get rid of the sums completely.